# How to avoid full class name restriction in JPQL?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to use `select p from Person p` instead of  `select p from xxx.xxx.Person`, but I can not find the corresponding configuration item.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add repository code to your question

Comment: JPQL **allows** you to use `select p FROM {entityName}` ! The entity name does not include package names by default. Since you don't post your entity, there is nothing more to say. And any "Spring Repository" code has no bearing on that

Comment: Can you share your application context.xml?